# Will Apple EarPods functions work with an Android phone?

Tags: ear-phones

Will the Apple EarPods microphone and volume functionality work with Android phones?

Comment: You had several questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your other questions, but feel free to ask it separately if a simple Google search doesn't help to answer them.

Comment: Please SPECIFY your Android device to get more accurate answer.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I have a Nexus 5

Comment: On my Sony Xperia Z3 Compact the mic works only if I hold the volume up remote button. Volume up and down doesn't work.

Comment: The audio will work, if you have a 3.5 mm headphone jack. You will find that Android and Apple mostly use the same button for Pause / Next Song (the middle click on the wire). However, the volume control will not as Android uses an entirely different structure.

Answer (score 3):

The audio output will work fine with any Android phone with a 3.5 mm headphone jack. The audio input from the microphone on the EarPods will only work on compatible Android devices—this is not guaranteed. As far as I am aware, there are no Android devices which work with the remote controls on the wire.

Answer (score 2):

As you have probably Goolged the answer and found that there are to many possible combinations, without knowing your specific Android model  the generic answers is:

As already answered by George Garside, the audio output will work (you will be able to hear).

The extra functionality like Microphone input works on most HTC phones.

The earpods work on HTC phones (Android & Windows Phones). They do not work on Samsung & Nokia phones. The headset works on any device with a 3.5mm jack, but the mic only works on HTC phones. There may be an exception.

The Start/Stop playing does not work on most phones, but it has been reported that using a Application called Meridian player and Droid phone it kindoff works.

So why is that and what can you do about it.

Just give you some background: From the outside the plugs look very much alike, but inside the engineers have decided (for unknown reasons) to switch functions for microphone).

[image: iphone plug]

So what can you do about that: you would need an adapter(bridge) to connect the 2 worlds of engineering.

Answer (score 1):

seems everything works with galaxy s4.. and galaxy tab 4

Comment: My apologies. I deleted this in error. It is an answer to the question being asked. You could improve this question by mentioning what version of the Android OS you're running and what functions from the iPhone headphones work (volume, play/pause, track changes, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Microphone and start/stop works on my galaxy core 2. Ut the volume remote does not.

Answer (score 0):

I just migrated from iPhone 4S to Samsung Galaxy Note 2 (Cyanogen Mod 12.1), and I can confirm the following:

The audio, microphone, and play/pause button all work. The volume up/down buttons do not work, while the volume up/down buttons from the stock Samsung headset works. Headset control apps within Android failed to solve the problem.