# How can I use EarPods with a dumb phone

Tags: headphones, microphone

I would like to use Apple EarPods with a Nokia 130 (dumb phone). I only need sound and microphone to work. I don't expect the volume control to work, since I assume it's proprietary.

1. Inserting the EarPods directly into the Nokia gives no sound at all. If I keep the connector halfway in, I get sound, but this is obviously not a permanent solution.
2. I tried an adapter with a female connector for the EarPods (4 pins) and a male connector (3 pins) for the Nokia. This gives me sound, but the microphone does not work.
3. I also tried using a cheap EarPods copy on the Nokia, which works for both sound and microphone (even if it has 4 pins like the original EarPods...!), but with bad quality (no bass).

Can someone recommend an adapter where:

- Sound works
- Microphone works
- Does not degrade audio quality
- Is as small and simple as possible

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/137203/88313). It's not an exact duplicate but some of the answers might help you while waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is a little more interesting than it appears on the surface.

Both your old Nokia and the EarPods use a 3.5mm audio jack with support for four "poles", each one providing a different purpose. Each one has left, right, ground, and microphone. [However, your old Nokia uses the OMTP standard, while the EarPods use the CTIA/AHJ standard.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)#TRRS_standards) This means the ground and microphone are switched between the two.

[image]

You'll need an adapter like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MR2SPAP) to get the EarPods working properly.

Comment: I bought an "OMTP/CTIA headset adapter" at a local shop. When used between the Nokia 130 and the Apple EarPods, the headset icon shows on the Nokia (which it doesn't when connecting the EarPods without an adapter), but the sound is distorted (sounds like peak clipping), and the microphone doesn't work at all. Out of curiosity, I tried it between a Mac and the EarPods: The sound and microphone work as normal, just as if I had used to adapter at all. How do I interpret these test results, and how do I proceed to make the EarPods work with the Nokia?

Comment: I'm really not sure. That's the only thing I could think of.

Comment: Do the EarPods themselves do any modification or amplification of the sound? (I assume not, but that's what it sounds like...)

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: http://www.cablechick.com.au/cables/35mm-4-pole-trrs-standards-bi-directional-adapter-ctia-to-omtp.html: "Apple hand-free kits and earbuds with an inline microphone for phone chat on Apple products are not compatible with any other equipment because of the way Apple uses the Mic and Ground lines for call accept/cancel and media controls. This adapter is not able to convert iPhone earbuds for use with non-Apple devices." Can you confirm this?

Comment: @forthrin I'll see about testing with another device I have and get back to you.

Comment: If you, or anyone else on the planet, can make the EarPods work on a Nokia dumb phone, I'll be very interested. Note that only listening and talking is necessary. I obviously don't expect the buttons on the microphone to work.

Comment: @forthrin The only Nokia dumb phone I have is old enough I don't think it has a four-pole jack, but I'll try it with some other non-Apple phones to see if I can confirm the cablechick post.

Comment: @forthrin I tried it with a Nexus 6P, and the mic and inline controls worked fine. Unfortunately the dumb Nokias I have are too old to have a 3.5mm jack. If you'd like I can test with a smart Nokia phone, but I doubt it'll give you any useful info and I'll have to do some shenanigans first with it.

Comment: The only one I found in my own country didn't work. There are other brands available from online shops abroad, but their appearance and description is identical, so I'm reluctant to try this blindly. If you run into someone with a dumb-phone made in recent years (preferably a Nokia 1xx), let me know if you're able to test it.

Comment: @forthrin Will do.